# KDE Application Launcher hidden settings

Tags: kde, settings

Recently, I installed Kubuntu in a virtual machine, and noticed that the application launcher is different from the application launcher in my normal Arch/KDE install. Mainly, no option to pin it, and transparency. A brief look at the settings yields no results. I was wondering where these settings are located, or if there is some config file. I am in no rush, but I am interested in the transparency.

Comment: Arch is a rolling release distro and Kubuntu isn't, so is it possible the differences are due to Arch running a newer version of Kickoff?

Comment: What package is it a part of?

Comment: It's the default application launcher for KDE Plasma. You can check your KDE version with `kdeinit5 --version`. There are some settings in ~/.config/plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc but I don't see anything related to pinning or transparency. Also, which settings are for which applet are not obvious in this file.

Comment: The default launcher from before KDE Plasma 5.21 is now called Kickoff/Legacy: https://userbase.kde.org/Plasma/Kickoff/Legacy and the widget can be found here: https://store.kde.org/p/1468103

Comment: Oh, and find your Plasma version with `plasmashell --version`. Certainly simpler than trying to figure it out based on the KDE version. Sorry!

Comment: Is it in the theme?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know where the actual Kickoff plasmoid (widget) resides. You might ask in r/KDE on Reddit.